# Are there any UI's that can work with Azure Cosmos MongoDB Gateway Mode?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

My company has a hard outbound network firewall rule that blocks everything except port 443. This blocks Mongo Compass from doing a direct connect to the cosmosdb via connection string. Is there any way to connect it to the Gateway API? Or are there any other desktop UI's that will work with Azure Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the port for a MongoDB API account on Cosmos DB.

You can connect to the Mongo shell in the Azure Portal for your Cosmos DB account as that is over port 443, but there's no option I know of that allows you to connect to it.

Comment: Yes, and that's what we've been doing but the shell is incredibly lacking. Just wondering if there are any known clients or UI's that can use the gateway API similar to the shell that are maybe not quite as bad.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no 3rd party tools that will work because the service will only accept connections via the standard Mongo ports. One suggestion I have is to provision an Azure Virtual Desktop, install your Mongo tools on there and run that. I think this will work since clients connect to it via port 443. However, firewall needs to open for TCP and UDP. More details here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/prerequisites#network. If this works, let me know. I'll add it to the answer so others can find it.

Comment: Yeah I think that may be what we end up doing. I was also considering creating a VM and running a cheesey proxy to the right ports but securing that properly seems like a real issue.